# Cannot play embedded videos on facebook wall unless SSL is disabled

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming

I am trying to embed (non-You Tube) videos on a Facebook wall so that when the user clicks on them, the video plays on the wall. What's happening is: if the user is not logged in or has SSL disabled, it works. However, if they access the page securely with an "https:" scheme or if they are logged in with SSL enabled, when they click on the video, a new tab is launched with the address of the page where the video resides.

I have researched this problem. The two solutions I have are, updating the OpenGraph metadata on the page and providing an SSL enabled version of the page. I have tried adding og metadata - initially I tried just adding the following:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

That didn't work, and the facebook debugger was complaining about a few missing metadata tags, so I added those (type, url, etc.). Now when I run it through the debugger, I don't get any warnings, and it now reports:

*When this URL is shared on facebook, it is treated as a certain type. By putting meta tags on this page, you can influence how it is shared.
Video
status  Video embedding on Facebook enabled*

I am blocked from proceeding. I can do anything about the SSL until my boss gets back, however, I don't see how that matters, considering the video works properly when SSL is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a meta tag detailing where the secure URL for your video is:

```
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://some/awesome.swf" />
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ for more info.

Comment: OK, I suspected that. However, I looked at metadata from some videos embedded through youtube and vimeo, none of them have any metadata to suggest they were making a secure connection. Reverbnation, on the other hand, does use a "https:" scheme in the value for the og:video property.

Comment: For some very large sites (like youtube and vimeo) we figure out the URL for the secure versions of the swf automagically. For everyone else you have to explicitly tell us where to look.

I'm kinda surprised that just putting a secure URL in the og:video tag doesn't work (i.e. not having an insecure one at all) but I can't remember exactly how it all works.

If you can't get it working with og:video:secure_url comment here with the URL that you're struggling with and I can take a further look. I wrote most of the code for the secure video embedding so between us I'm sure we can crack it! :)

Comment: Thanks @mrtom, that's about what I figured. I also looked at the response data from the facebook call to "embed_inline.php" (or something like that) that is initiated when I click on the image link for a youtube video on the wall. In it, I saw that the url for the swf at youtube.com is a secure 'https:'.

Answer (score 1):

Note after some testing, The latest behavior for facebook embed with in-wall playback is that both og:video and og:video:secure_url must be https, or if only og:video, have that be https instead of http.