# How to embed my own HTML5/flash video player in facebook wall post (using rails + koala)?

Tags: facebook, html, video, koala

I would like to embed my own HTML5 (with a flash backup) player on a Facebook wall post.
I'm using rails and ruby Koala.
I have seen this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ for meta tags that can be added, but it's either for a link to my web page or to a video file to load.

Appreciate if anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player

Here's example of the og:tags on the link being shared so facebook can pickup the customer video player:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Big Buck Bunny" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/bunny.png" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.example.com/jwplayer/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fbunny.flv&autostart=true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is still possible to put only a flash player?

Comment: Never tried it.  I found your answer by Google, not by personal experience.  Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, Somehow I can't get it to work :(.
I'm directing to my player, and trying to show a video with facebook link, such as:

http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-ash4/v/443893/65/13485868684_297.mp4

Comment: Actually, how do I know my player can use the parameters this way? (source=[player path]?file=[file path]?
What if it needs different parameters?

Comment: I really don't know much about flash.  You will have to experiment with it to see if different parameters will work.

Comment: My custom video didn't work until I added the `og:video:secure_url` property, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8828688/500309

Comment: Is the player mendatory? I was assuming the putting: `content="myfile.mp4"` would be enought. I tried to use [divine-player](https://github.com/cameronhunter/divine-player-swf) and I tried `http://myhostname/divine-player.swf?video=myfile.mp4` and still Facebook doesn't preview it as a video...