# Playing inline swf video posted on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

When I post .SWF content using facebook API , after on the wall it's not possible playing it inline,  if i click on the thumbnail it redirect me on an external page and opens the video in full screen.

In the api tag source i'm passing the mp4 streamed video url as follow...

source = 'http://' + document.location.host + '/htutilities/flash/player.swf?videoFile=' + escape(movieUrl);

What i'm wronging ? Facebook whitelist is a reality or not ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved.
I discovered that the reason for which the player didn't play inline but redirect on external page (in fullscreen mode) was that the player.swf was hosted on **http** domain.
Facebook play inline only https video hosted and redirect others.
First of all i loaded my swf player on **https** domain using google sites creating a public directory and posting on facebook using the old fb api -->

FB.ui({
         method:  'stream.publish',
     display: 'popup',
     message: 'Facebook Connect',

```
attachment: 
            {       

               name        : 'Test ore 10:24',       
               caption     : 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',       
               description : ('desc'),

               'media' : 

                         [
                             {  

                                 "type"           : "flash",
                                 "swfsrc"         : "https://sites.google.com                       /site/myRootDirectory /Home/player.swf?videoFile="  + escape("rtmp://myStream"),
                                 "imgsrc"         : "http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg",
                                 "width"          : "80", 
                                 "height"         : "60",
                                 "expanded_width" : "360", 
                                 "expanded_height": "250"

                             }
                          ] 

              }

   })
```

The result was the video show a player with the controls inline but the buffering stops at 80%.
In the second attempt i loaded an mp4 video on google sites referencing it the swfsrc. 
Facebook creates an invisible object inline.
 Also i follow this post -->

[Cannot play embedded videos on facebook wall unless SSL is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826913/cannot-play-embedded-videos-on-facebook-wall-unless-ssl-is-disabled)

without success.

P.S. in both cases opening the swfsrc in the browser the video goes in play normally.